# Firebase Auth: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How do I set `appVerificationDisabledForTesting` to `true` and in which file? If I add `firebase.auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true` then how to import firebase in the file ?

`firebase` is not importing for this statement:

```
firebase.auth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code sample you provided is for the old namespaced Firebase SDK. In the modern modular Firebase SDK, you need to get an instance of the [`Auth` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md) ([`getAuth()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getauth) replaces `firebase.auth()`) and then access its [`settings` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.auth.md#authsettings):

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

initializeApp(/* ... firebase config ... */);

getAuth().settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = true;
```

Refer to the [modular SDK upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) for details on how to update out of date code samples.